# Applicable Regression Models for complex X(predictor) vs Y(response) plot?

Tags: r, regression

http://i43.tinypic.com/8yz893.png

The figure in the link shows the relation between one of my predictors(vms) and the response(responses[i]).

We can distinguish many log-like trends within the same graph.
According to this,   **a single value of my predictor can be mapped to many values of the response**.

- Is this acceptable or should I be alarmed that there is a problem with my data?
- What regression model would seem more suitable for this picture?

Comment: This question should be on Crossvalidated - stack overflow is for programing questions rather than statistical advice

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about graphical representation of the fit of a statistical model (i.e. http://stats.stackexchange.com )


Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an R question, but rather a general statistics question, so you may get downvoted, but I'll try to help you out.

There's nothing wrong with having individual values of the predictor mapping to multiple values of response. This would be a problem if you were defining and evaluating a function, but you're not technically evaluating a function, you're evaluating the statistical relationship between two variables. You will then **create** a functional form to model this relationship.

It seems to me that a conventional OLS model would be very inappropriate here, as one of the assumptions of OLS is that the relationship between the predictor and the outcome variable is linear, which is clearly is not in this case. The relationship actually looks a lot like a 1/x curve, so you may want to try a 1/x transformation and see where that gets you.